# Formula to calculate thickness from size/schedule information in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to excel world and trying to learn excel formulas.

I have thickness data against size/schedule in an excel file as below

[image]

First column represents the size while the first row is the thickness.
I need a formula to calculate thickness against size/schedule. For example in the above image if size is 6 and schedule is 10 then thickness should be returned as 3.40.

In short: I need a formula to fill in this below sheet(image below) from the above sheet (image above)

[image]

What I have tried is, I have tried to make a vlookup table (called it Test) for the image 1's sheet which is the table that contains thickness against size/schedule and tried to put the vlookup formula like below

=VLOOKUP(L2, Test, 1, FALSE).

But this gives me the column 1 against the entry which will be found, so definitely this is not the right way, so can some 1 guide me to the right way here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work for you

=VLOOKUP(L2, Test, MATCH(O2,Test,0), FALSE).

Comment: i made another table for the first row 'Test1' and changed the above to 
`=VLOOKUP(L2, Test, MATCH(O2,Test1,0), FALSE).`
and it worked like a charm :)